# Copy the selected listbox items to another but same workbook?

Tags: vba, excel

My question is how can I amend this following code so that it will copy and paste in the another worksheets("Purged Cartons") in another workbook called "Purged.xlsx". I don't want to use workbook.add because I do not want to create a new workbook everytime the code runs. I want to copy the same named workbook. Please advise. Thank you.

```
Dim book As Workbook

 Set book = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\_tanwen\Documents\wyw6\Purged.xlsx")

      With Sheet1
            For Each index In myindex
                myid = ListBox3.List(index, 0)
                Set rtarget = .Range("A:A").Find(myid, [a1]) '~~> Assuming ID's in ColA
                If Not rtarget Is Nothing Then Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A:A").Find(myid, [a1]).Resize(1, 8). _
                Copy book.Worksheets("Purged Cartons").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
                rtarget.EntireRow.Delete
                counter = counter + 1
                Set rtarget = Nothing
            Next
            End With
```

I tried to run the above code. My "book" is opened but this line is causing the error saying specified name not found.

```
Copy book.Worksheets("Purged Cartons").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
```

Comment: It will be much easier to discover what the problem is if you split that single statement across several lines, performing the Find, Resize and Copy separately. It is possibly the Find that is failing, rather than the reference to the "Purged" workbook.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve it.

The solution is that you will have to declare a variable for your active workbook too.

So I amended the following code and it works.

```
Dim wb1 As Workbook
Dim wb2 As Workbook


Set wb1 = ActiveWorkbook --> add this
Set wb2 = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\_tanwen\Documents\wyw6\Purged.xlsx")


    For Each index In myindex
    myid = ListBox3.List(index, 0)
    Set rtarget = .Range("A:A").Find(myid, [a1])         
    If Not rtarget Is Nothing Then add this -->wb1.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A:A").Find(myid,    [a1]).Resize(1, 8). _
    Copy wb2.Worksheets("Purged Cartons").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
    rtarget.EntireRow.Delete
    counter = counter + 1
    Set rtarget = Nothing
    Next
    End With
```